# How to make an angular webapp supported in webos lg tv webbrowser?

Tags: angular

I have developed an angular web application in angular 8. This application works on most of the browsers, however, when I try to open a web page from the webbrowser of lg smart tv, the application opens but I am unable to login.

How can I make angular web application runnable in lg smart tv webbrowser?

My polyfills.ts file is as below:

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
// import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
// import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
// import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata';


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depend on WebOs version.

WebOS Browser is a Lg built-in homemade browser made by Lg. So this kind of browsers usually lack features and latest Javascript updates.

Since webOS TV 3.X  the built in Web browser is using Chromium engine. But if the webOS TV is 1.X or 2.X then it is using old versions of webkit engine.

First you need to discover which is the webOS version you want to support.

http://webostv.developer.lge.com/discover/specifications/web-engine/

You may try visiting this link from the WebOS web browser and check its compatibility:

kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

Comment: I want to support webOS TV 4.x which is using chromium 53. Is there any way to make angular webapp supported.

Comment: Chromium 53 is way too old (2016). I remember using Angular 5 with it. You can try adding pollyfills or, the worst way, an Angular 5 project.

Comment: I researched for browser support but did not find the option for chromium. How can I add chromuim in polyfills ?

Comment: Any updates regarding your issue, as we face the same thing.